# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C

Tags: c

This is a program for checking the leap year. Could you kindly tell me why I'm getting this error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int year=0;
    printf("Enter the year  to be Validated \n");
    scanf("%d",year);
    if (year%4==0){
        printf ("one");
        if (year%100==0){
            printf ("two");
            if (year%400==0){
                printf("Leap Year");
            }
                else{
                    printf("Non Leap year");


            }}}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `&year` instead of `year`

Comment: `scanf("%d", &year);`

Comment: Get a couple of [good beginners books to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and read more about how to use [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass pointer to `scanf`.

```
scanf("%d",year);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &year);
```

Comment: @HardipinderSingh consider accepting the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I was supposed to do that. Thank you :) @AnderBiguri